# Page Slide Transition advice flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

So basically, what I want to do is be able to not only swipe a page, but also to move it from side to side, but also have an animation for the transition to the next page. Something like this, but with a bounce in animation once slid:

[image]

The only similar thing I've done is using a GestureDetector or Dismissible.

Do I have to create this as widget from ground up and if so, how should I approach this? Or is there already a widget for this?

Comment: `PageController.page` gives you a current page as `double` so you can use it inside your `PageController`'s listener

Comment: Umm... I've never really used PageView or PageController before. I tried PageController.page but it just shows its undefined. Is that part of a different package or something?